# Agregar librería estática propia a un proyecto

Tags: c++, netbeans

Me ha surgido la duda de cómo agregar una librería propia a un proyecto nuevo en Netbeans específicamente, es mi espacio de trabajo.

Supongamos que tengo una librería estática simple llamada (cat).

```
C:\Users\{nameuser}\Documents\NetBeansProjects\cat
```

Cuenta con una clase llamada igual que el proyecto (cat).

[image: Básicamente los archivos de la librería]

(El código de la clase no es relevante)

Ahora cual seria el paso a seguir para configurar y poder utilizar esa propia librería, en un otro proyecto. (hacerle #include ).

Nota: Respuestas con imágenes serían didácticas y apreciadas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta esto del sitio en inglés (yo es que sólo utilizo netbeans para java):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264294/netbeans-how-to-include-other-c-static-library-project

Básicamente siempre se indican los directorios para los archivos de cabecera en las opciones de compilación y lo que son propiamente librerias al linker.

En codeblocks: Settings, compiler, search directories y linker settings.

Comment: Exacto, me ayudo tu respuesta; pude agregar la librería a mi provecto, te agradezco mucho.